# openURL for Mobile Safari is failing for iOS v12.2

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, xcuitest

So I'm trying to open a url on Safari browser on the new iPad Mini 5(iOS v12.2).

```
#define SAFARI_APP @"com.apple.mobilesafari"

XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] initWithBundleIdentifier:MOBILE_SAFARI_APP];
[app launch];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"];
if (url) {
  NSLog(@"++++ Opening url: %@ ++++", url);
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
      NSLog(@"Opened url - %@", url);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Failed to open website");
    }
  }];
}
```

This code launches the safari browser but doesn't open the website. I can see the `Failed to open website` statement in Log.

Any help is appreciated.